# reading CloudWatch Logs Log Group (/aws/eks/my-eks/cluster)

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, terraform, amazon-eks

I've been trying to get past this issue of :
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

```
╷
│ Error: reading CloudWatch Logs Log Group (/aws/eks/my-eks/cluster): operation error CloudWatch Logs: DescribeLogGroups, https response error StatusCode: 400, RequestID: b5b8a4a3-697b-43e1-bd97-a731bfbd492b, api error AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:iam::471387841990:user/dikachi is not authorized to perform: logs:DescribeLogGroups on resource: arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:471387841990:log-group::log-stream: because no identity-based policy allows the logs:DescribeLogGroups action
│
│   with module.eks.aws_cloudwatch_log_group.this[0],
│   on .terraform\modules\eks\main.tf line 76, in resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "this":
│   76: resource "aws_cloudwatch_log_group" "this" {
```

decided to create an inline policy in my IAM user but still its still giving me the same error

[image: the inline policy i created]

What do you suggest ?

Comment: Consider to ask sys-admin questions on https://serverfault.com instead. Stack Overflow is for programming questions.

Comment: this simply means that user`dikachi ` does't have required permissions for get/create logs in cloudwatch

Answer (score 0):

Your current policy has improper resources in policy statements, the below policy should resolve your issue:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement":
    [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":
            [
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<accountid>:log-group:<log-group-name>:log-stream:*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action":
            [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
                "logs:PutRetensionPolicy",
                "logs:TagResource"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:<accountid>:log-group:*"
        }
    ]
}
```